# Common symbols '\p{S}' not been 'matched' using boost wregex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I am using the code below to try and match symbols using regex, (as an example, I am trying to match the circle star symbol, http://graphemica.com/%E2%9C%AA)

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

//...
std::wstring text = L"a✪c";
auto re = L"(\\p{S}|\\p{L})+?";
boost::wregex r(re);
boost::regex_token_iterator<std::wstring::const_iterator>
  i(boost::make_regex_token_iterator(text, r, 1)), j;
while (i != j)
{
  std::wstring x = *i;
  ++i;
}
//...
```

The byte value of `text` is `{97, 10026, 99}`, (or `{0x61,0x272A, 0x63}').
So it is a valid symbol.

The code matches the 2 letters, `'a'` `0x61` and ``` 'c'``0x63 ```, but not the symbol `✪` (`0x272A`).
I have tried it with a couple of other symbols and none of them work, (© for example).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Interesting, both `✪` and `©` belong to `\p{So}` category. What if you just use `\\p{So}`, or `auto re = L"[\\p{So}\\p{S}\\p{L}]";`? (Your `+?` is redundant if you want to match 1 symbol at a time).

Comment: It does not seem to work, I get the following error 
`Escape sequence was neither a valid property nor a valid character class name.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression: '(\p{So}>>>HERE>>>)'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Boost.Regex documentation explicitly states that [there's no support for Unicode-specific character classes](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html) when using `boost::wregex`.

If you want this functionality, you'll need to [build Boost.Regex with ICU support](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html#boost_regex.install.building_with_unicode_and_icu_su) enabled then use the `boost::u32regex` type instead of `boost::wregex`.