# Common symbols '\pS' not been 'matched' using std::wregex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, std

I am using the code below to try and match symbols using regex, (as an example, I am trying to match the circle star symbol, http://graphemica.com/%E2%9C%AA)

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::wsmatch matches;
  std::wstring x = L"✪";
  //  std::wregex e(L"(\\pS)+");
  std::wregex e(L"([[:S:]]+)");
  if (std::regex_match(x, matches, e))
  {
    // never reached
    std::cout << "Never reached";
  } 

  std::cout << "Bye.";

  return 0;
}
```

The symbol ✪ (0x272A) is not matched, I also tried with other symbols and none of them work, (© for example).

I tried `[:S:]`, `\pS` and `\p{S}`, none of them work, (the last one throws an exception)

This is a *similar*, (but not the same namespace), problem as the one as with the boost library, ([Common symbols '\p{S}' not been 'matched' using boost wregex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525120/common-symbols-ps-not-been-matched-using-boost-wregex?noredirect=1#comment64444926_38525120))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither ECMAScript 3rd ed. nor POSIX regex grammars support Unicode category character classes. You can form them yourself using `\u` and `\U`-based character ranges, but hoping for things like `\p{So}` is a lost cause with present specifications.

As I answered on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543269/636019), if you really want to use them, Boost.Regex supports them via the `boost::u32regex` if built with ICU support enabled. (PCRE/PCRE2 support them as well, but as with most C libraries, I hesitate to recommend these for new C++ code.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes sense now why neither work.
I am curious about the last part of your answer, I have used pcre2 in the past, (and I like it), so I wonder why you would not recommend it.

Comment: @FFMG : Because this is tagged `c++` and `c++11`, not `c`. Personally, if I asked a C++ question and got a C answer/recommendation I'd be rather annoyed. ;-]